# C#: Optimize LinQ query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm writing a LinQ query where one of the columns is a total (pscount) and it's being a little bit slow. I'm quite sure the culprit is the subselect to calculate pscount, and I'm also quite sure this query could be optimized. How can I do that?

```cs
var q =
    from
        finca in this.db.finca
    join direccion in db.direccion 
        on new { id = finca.direccion_id } equals new { id = direccion.direccion_id }
    join ambito in db.ambito_geografico
        on new { id = direccion.ambito_id } equals new { id = (short?)ambito.ambito_id }
    join acometida in this.db.acometida
        on new { id = finca.acometida_defecto_id } equals new { id = acometida.acometida_id }
    join planificacion in this.db.planificacion
        on new { id = finca.planificacion_defecto_id } equals new { id = planificacion.planificacion_id }
    select
        new FincaViewModel
        {
            direccion = direccion.direccion_postal_1, //.direccion_postal_1,
            ambito = ambito.descripcion,
            acometida = acometida.nombre, //.nombre,
            pscount = (
                from p in this.db.puntosuministroview select p
            ).Where(psum => psum.concesion_id == finca.concesion_id
                && psum.planificacion_id == finca.planificacion_defecto_id
                && psum.acometida_id == finca.acometida_defecto_id).Count(),
            concesion_id = finca.concesion_id,
            planificacion = planificacion.nombre_planificacion,
            disponible_contratacion = finca.disponible_contratacion ? General.Si : General.No,
        };
```

Comment: Some definitions would help in reproducing and testing the code.

Comment: First of all, Entity Framework is not always great at translating queries. So I would try to reproduce the query in plain SQL and see if there is any performance difference. If not you might need to change the database, see if any index is missing, maybe add a view, or de-normalize for better performance.

Comment: I would use a subquery in the from clause instead of a subselect in the select clause. This will allow the query engine to optimize the subquery and execute it only once, instead of once for each outer query row.

Comment: can't you do the on-clause directly? `on finca.direccion_id equals direccion.direccion_id`

Comment: Thanks all for the contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var countsQuery = 
    from p in this.db.puntosuministroview 
    group p by new { p.concesion_id, p.planificacion_id, p.acometida_i } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.concesion_id, 
        g.Key.planificacion_id, 
        g.Key.acometida_i,
        count = g.Count()
    };

var q =
    from
        finca in this.db.finca
    join direccion in db.direccion 
        on new { id = finca.direccion_id } equals new { id = direccion.direccion_id }
    join ambito in db.ambito_geografico
        on new { id = direccion.ambito_id } equals new { id = (short?)ambito.ambito_id }
    join acometida in this.db.acometida
        on new { id = finca.acometida_defecto_id } equals new { id = acometida.acometida_id }
    join planificacion in this.db.planificacion
        on new { id = finca.planificacion_defecto_id } equals new { id = planificacion.planificacion_id }
    join c in countsQuery
        on new { finca.concesion_id, finca.planificacion_id, finca.acometida_i } equals new { c.concesion_id, c.planificacion_id, c.acometida_i } into gj
    from c in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new FincaViewModel
    {
        direccion = direccion.direccion_postal_1, //.direccion_postal_1,
        ambito = ambito.descripcion,
        acometida = acometida.nombre, //.nombre,
        pscount = ((int?)c.count) ?? 0,
        concesion_id = finca.concesion_id,
        planificacion = planificacion.nombre_planificacion,
        disponible_contratacion = finca.disponible_contratacion ? General.Si : General.No,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Svyatoslav Danyliv. With the help of a Stopwatch I was easily able to measure and compare timings, and the results have given you 10 points. 110 milliseconds (mine) vs 46 (yours). Simple and working. Bravo.